# Mongoose find and lookup

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am in a company wanting to list the User Stories of the team.
I have two tables.
One contains the US.
The other contains Sprints which themselves contain the US ids that were made during this sprint.

Shemas looks something like this.

```
const Userstories = mongoose.Schema({
    Name: String,  
    Date: Date
});

const Sprint= mongoose.Schema({
    Name: String,
    Userstories: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "userStory"}],
    Author: String,
    Date: Date
});
```

Sometimes I need the US list for a specific Sprint.

And for that I used the lookup function.
But I do not know why, I can't do a find at the same time.
In the end I did this:

```
Sprint.aggregate([{
        $lookup: {
            from: 'userstories',
            localField: 'Userstories',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'Userstories'
        }
    }
const photos = agregate.find(us => us._id == id);
```

I do the aggregation first and find it after.

But I guess doing it that way is costly in computation time.

That why I wanted to know if Mongoose optimizes this kind of case?
And if not, how can I write my request more properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the Sprint using a [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) aggregation.

So you can use the following example get route:

```js
router.get("/sprints/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  const result = await Sprint.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: ObjectId(id),
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "userstories",
        localField: "Userstories",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "Userstories",
      },
    },
  ]);
  res.send(result);
});
```

Let's say you have these 2 Userstories documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ecd60f21f3c84289488d6d9"),
    "Name" : "story 1",
    "Date" : ISODate("2020-05-26T21:33:22.543+03:00")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ecd60fb1f3c84289488d6da"),
    "Name" : "story 2",
    "Date" : ISODate("2020-05-26T21:33:31.692+03:00")
},
```

And this sprint document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ecd610f1f3c84289488d6db"),
    "Userstories" : [
        ObjectId("5ecd60f21f3c84289488d6d9"),
        ObjectId("5ecd60fb1f3c84289488d6da")
    ],
    "Name" : "Sprint 1",
    "Author" : "Author 1",
    "Date" : ISODate("2020-05-26T21:33:51.928+03:00")
}
```

The result will be like this for this sprint:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5ecd610f1f3c84289488d6db",
        "Userstories": [
            {
                "_id": "5ecd60f21f3c84289488d6d9",
                "Name": "story 1",
                "Date": "2020-05-26T18:33:22.543Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ecd60fb1f3c84289488d6da",
                "Name": "story 2",
                "Date": "2020-05-26T18:33:31.692Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Sprint 1",
        "Author": "Author 1",
        "Date": "2020-05-26T18:33:51.928Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: I had already tried but I did not know why I had no results. By seeing your code I understood that it was necessary to use the ObjectId () function, which we do not do with the find () function of mongoose.
It works now.
Thank you !